# A critique of the epistemoloical models of religion

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-religion

I'm interested to find any existing critique of the epistemological models by which religions (especially the various branches of Christianity) determine their theological conclusions.

What I currently understand is that, for example, the [Wesleyan Quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesleyan_Quadrilateral) has four different sources in coming to theological conclusions. Various branches of Christianity place different priority on these sources. I am interested to understand how one can critique such models (understand their strengths and weaknesses).

FURTHER DETAILS REGARDING @Dave AND @PeterSmiths COMMENTS

Dave  - I understand your point and I take PeterSmiths point also. William Lane Craig makes a distinction between 'knowing' your faith to be true, and being able to 'show' your faith to be true, which I think is relevant to yours and the subsequent comments.

I am concerned with epistemological models between different denominations and think that this is very relevant when it comes to the theological conclusions that they draw. This is especially relevant for contentious issues in the church (for example the roles of women, or homosexuality). For example, Catholicism places a higher emphasis on the role of tradition than Pentecostal churches, and Pentecostal churches place more of an emphasis on 'experience' that Catholic churches. What I'm looking for is a critique of the different models that different church branches use, with a view to uncover any linkages to variation in positions regarding contentious issues.

Comment: If you're primarily trying to work out the differences between Christian groups, there's an entire SE devoted to the topic of Christianity. Can you make clearer what you want done in philosophy relative to this? (We're not equipped to do a taxonomy of views nor do theological critiques of the merits/demerits of them)...

Comment: In addition to this arguably being a better fit for http://christianity.stackexchange.com, it may be too broad to be answerable as currently posed.  There are innumerable branches of Christianity, many with subtle or broad theological differences.  You might try focusing in on one or two --Catholic and Episcopal might be good examples, since they are currently at opposite poles on the subject of LGBT inclusion in the church.  **"Are Catholic and Episcopal differences on LGBT issues traceable to different epistemological commitments?"**

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will have a look at christianity.stackexchange.com. In regards to what I'm after in philosophy, I was hopeful that there might be existing literature which reviews epsitemological models across religions (I've just expressed the Christian detailed example). If that is not the case, thank you for your thoughts.